# Composition types of music

Tags: theory, composition, history

Composition types in Western classical music. 
Is it possible for people to recognize the types of composition without the knowledge of the name given for the piece?

Comment: Providing a list, which may or may not be complete, is of very little help to anyone reading it. Vtc.

Comment: I'm not so sure this is all that off topic. Maybe it could be edited for clarity, but I feel that the real question here is not "Can someone give me a list of all the composition types?", but rather "How and why did the composition types develop over time?" which is an excellent, very on topic question if you ask me. Admittedly, my own answer only address the first "off topic" part of the question and I only read into it more after the fact. Honestly, at this point, I would blame my answer for being off topic more than the question itself and I am considering editing my answer to address this.

Comment: Even the individual questions "how and why did the sonata, or concerto, or toccata, develop" are too broad.  Long books have been written about each of these.

Answer (score 2):

> How many composition types are there?

855, by counting the entries in a contemporary [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_music_styles).

Less jokingly, a list of composition types will teach someone no more about western music than a list of, say, the names of Chinese herbs would teach me about Chinese cuisine.
More useful is to read an introductory textbook about Western classical music, or study a "Music Appreciation 101" course.

Although a general introduction is too broad for this Q & A web site, the books cited at the end of [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_period_(music)#Further_reading) article are a useful start.

Comment: but this is rather a comment than an answer ;)

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer.

Comment: 855 looks like an answer to me. The question is not marked 'off-topic'. .

Comment: 855 was only after A.H.'s valid objection!

Comment: Well, I am really grateful for the comment you've posted, but I was not asking about "genre".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "composition types" I would call these forms, or styles or even (in more modern terminology) genres. Since these are really just classifications or categories, **there are literally infinite possibilities**, so it's impossible to put an exact number on it.

**Here are the most common ones that I can think of:**
Auria
Ballade
Canon
Caprice
Concerto
Etude
Fugue
Impromptu
Nocturne
March
Mass
Minuet
Opera
Oratorio
Polonaise
Prelude
Rhapsody
Requiem
Scherzo
Sonata
Sonatina
Suite
Symphony
Toccata
Waltz

Comment: and all the inventions that haven't been invented yet ...

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer.